# Listing names with count of an argument in another table - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Not sure how to describe it, ive been searching the internet for a few hours and have gone pretty numb. I have two tables. One called hotel, the other called room. Pretty self explanatory but hotel is a list of hotels with 'hotelNo' as a primary key and with their city and name and that, while room has other info and 'hotelNo' as a foreign key to the hotel primary key.

hotel

```
+---------+---------------------+----------+
| hotelNo | hotelName           | city     |
+---------+---------------------+----------+
|       1 | Grosvenor Hotel     | Sydney   |
|       2 | ANA Hotel           | Sydney   |
|       3 | Great Mansion Hotel | Brisbane |
|       4 | Grand Hotel         | Brisbane |
|       5 | Central Hotel       | Sydney   |
|       6 | Airport Hotel       | Sydney   |
+---------+---------------------+----------+
```

and room

```
+--------+---------+------+--------+
| roomNo | hotelNo | type | rate   |
+--------+---------+------+--------+
|    101 |       1 | S    | 120.00 |
|    101 |       2 | D    | 100.00 |
|    101 |       3 | S    |  80.00 |
|    101 |       5 | D    | 180.00 |
|    102 |       1 | S    | 120.00 |
|    102 |       2 | S    |  80.00 |
|    102 |       3 | S    |  80.00 |
|    102 |       5 | K    | 190.00 |
|    103 |       1 | S    | 120.00 |
|    103 |       3 | D    | 100.00 |
|    103 |       5 | S    | 120.00 |
|    104 |       1 | D    | 150.00 |
|    104 |       4 | Q    | 100.00 |
|    104 |       5 | D    | 140.00 |
|    105 |       1 | D    | 150.00 |
|    105 |       4 | Q    | 500.00 |
|    106 |       1 | D    | 150.00 |
|    107 |       1 | Q    | 180.00 |
|    108 |       1 | Q    | 180.00 |
|    109 |       1 | Q    | 180.00 |
+--------+---------+------+--------+
```

The question I am asked is

"List the names of hotels in Sydney that have 3 or more rooms."

and i want my output to just be the name of the hotels

```
+---------------------+
| hotelName           |
+---------------------+
| Grosvenor Hotel     |
| Central Hotel       |
+---------------------+
```

Any help would be great, as i have some catching up todo. cheers

Comment: You are asked to use `COUNT`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. Try it; it's not very complicated.

Comment: Join the two tables, then use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY hotelNo` to get the count of rooms of each hotel.

Answer (score 0):

Just do what the above comment suggest, and join the two tables, aggregating by hotel:

```
SELECT
    h.hotelNo,
    h.hotelName
FROM hotel h
INNER JOIN room r
    ON h.hotelNo = r.hotelNo
GROUP BY
    h.hotelNo,
    h.hotelName
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Note that I select (and aggregate) using both the hotel name and the hotel's id number.  This is to cover a situation where possibly two hotels in Australia would happen to have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

As some spoilsports have shown the solution (sorry about that; this would have been a good execrcise for you), I am showing alternatives for the learning effect.

### Use IN

You only want to select hotel names. So why join at all?

```
select hotelname
from hotels
where hotelno in
(
  select hotelno
  from rooms
  group by hotelno
  having count(*) >= 3
)
order by hotelname;
```

### Aggregate before joining

If you want to show the count in the results, then join. Although the query gets longer and a tad more complicated, it is good style to aggregate before joining. This is especially helpful at times you need aggregates from different tables.

```
select h.hotelname, r.room_count
from hotels h
join
(
  select hotelno, count(*) as room_count
  from rooms
  group by hotelno
  having count(*) >= 3
) r on r.hotelno = h.hotelno
order by h.hotelname;
```